RootMe - TCP back to School Problema en C
El caso es que estoy haciendo un ejercicio de rootMe - Programacion -> TCP Back to school (el primero y el más fácil) esto es lo que dice:

Pues eso, que después de todo le tiempo que invertí resulta que funciona todo correctamente menos por la parte de que al enviar la respuesta, no recibo la bandera (osea la respuesta del servidor). Este es el código:
{

    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

    int toInt(char s[]) {
        int o, n;
        n = 0;
        for (o = 0; s[o] != '\0'; o++) {
            n = n * 10 + s[o] - '0';
        }
        return n;
    } 

    int main(void) {
        WSADATA wsadata;
        char buffer[1024];
        char enviar[sizeof(float)];
        char respuesta[32];
        int bytesReceived;
        int i;
        int np;
        int ns;
        char primero[10];
        char segundo[10];
        float primero_double;
        float segundo_double;
        BOOL status = TRUE;
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata) != 0) {
            printf("Error en WSAstartup\n");
            return -1;
        }

        SOCKET clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("Error al crear el socket\n");
            WSACleanup();
            return -2;
        }

        struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
        serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("212.129.38.224");
        serverAddress.sin_port = htons(52002);

        if (connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress))== SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("Error al conectar\n");
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }

        bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, (char *)&buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR || bytesReceived == 0) {
            printf("Error al recibir datos\n");
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }
        buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';

        printf("Mensaje recibido: %s\nbytesReceived: %d\n", buffer, bytesReceived);

        i = 0;
        np = 0;
        ns = 0;
        // Get the numbers and saving it in "primero" and "segundo"
        while (buffer[i+160] != '\0') {    
            if (buffer[i+160] >= '0' && buffer[i+160] <= '9') {
                if (status) {
                    primero[np] = buffer[i+160];
                    ++np;
                    if (buffer[i+160+1] == ' ') {
                        status = FALSE;
                    }
                } else {
                    segundo[ns] = buffer[i+160];
                    ++ns;
                }
            }
            ++i;
        }
        primero[np] = '\0';
        segundo[ns] = '\0';
        printf("primero: %s, segundo: %s\n", primero, segundo);
        // transforming string to int
        primero_float = toInt(primero);
        segundo_float = toInt(segundo);
        printf("primero_int: %.2f, segundo_int: %.2f\n", primero_float, segundo_float);

        // doing the actual math required in the exercise
        primero_float = sqrt(primero_float);
        segundo_float = primero_float * segundo_float;

        // rounding to the 2 decimals
        segundo_float = round(segundo_float * 100) / 100;
        printf("redondeado: %.2f\n", segundo_float);

        sprintf(enviar,"%.2f\n", segundo_float);
        printf("enviar: %s", enviar);
        send(clientSocket, &enviar, sizeof(enviar), 0);
        bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, (char *)&respuesta, sizeof(respuesta)-1, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR || bytesReceived == 0) {
            printf("Error al recibir datos\n");
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }
        respuesta[bytesReceived] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", respuesta);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();

        return 0;
    }
}

Como podéis ver estoy mandando el numero flotante tal como especifica el desafío (int o float) y lo estoy redondeando al segundo decimal. El valor es correcto eso seguro.
El problema es que como dije no recibo la respuesta del servidor, tengo mis hipótesis pero mejor no digo nada y no quedo en evidencia XD, ya sabéis lo que dicen: el que no se moja, no se sonroja <-- me lo acabo de inventar ahora, lo he mirado en internet y resulta que existe wow.
el OUTPUT:

Código de python que SI FUNCIONA, por si os sirve para mirar diferencias:
Este código aparte de que no es mío y me molesta bastante, no esta en C y me ENCANTARIA hacerlo en C que es lo que estoy estudiando
{

    import math
    import socket

    HOST = "challenge01.root-me.org"  # The server's hostname or IP address
    PORT = 52002  # The port used by the server

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        print("a="+str(data[171:174]))     
        print("b="+str(data[191:195]))
        a=math.sqrt(int(data[171:174]))
        b=int(data[191:195])*a
        r=round(b, 2)
        print(r)
        c=bytes(str(r)+"\n",'utf-8')
        print("c="+c.decode())

        # s.send(c.encode())
        s.send(c)
        data2=s.recv(1024)

    print(f"Received {data2!r}")
}


Recuerda que hay una conversión implícita de arreglo a puntero. No es necesario &enviar. Por cierto, en qué formato se envían los datos? Como texto? Y por qué enviar tiene el tamaño de un float?

@Mateo Si, es cierto que esta la conversión implícita de arreglo a puntero y es un fallo que no tengo en mi código, es una tontería, ahora mismo lo edito. La pregunta de porque enviar tiene el tamaño de un float es muy buena pregunta y vaya que si es buena, que es el error jajajaj, que verguenza. Muchisimas gracias Mateo por ayudarme, ahora mismo respondo la pregunta <3.

El problema reside en la línea:
char enviar[sizeof(float)];

Al estar estableciendo el tamaño de enviar al de float (4 bytes), no cabía la cadena formateada en esta:
sprintf(enviar,"%.2f\n", segundo_float);

Un ejemplo más práctico de lo que está pasando aquí es:
Imaginemos que el resultado de la operación es: 18032.42
Este número al formatearlo en sprintf quedaría: "18032.42\n\0"
Esto tiene un tamaño de 10 bytes, para nada igual que los míseros 4 bytes que le estaba estableciendo con: char enviar[sizeof(float)]
Otra error también es el tamaño del buffer respuesta, que esta establecido a 32 bytes, algo que posteriormente daría problemas porque no podría recibir toda la respuesta del servidor.
Esto nos lleva a la conclusión de que para solucionar este problema los cambios son:

cambio de: char enviar[sizeof(float)] -> char enviar[32]
cambio de: char respuesta[32] -> char respuesta[512]

Con esto el código final:
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int toInt(char s[]) {
    int o, n;
    n = 0;
    for (o = 0; s[o] != '\0'; o++) {
        n = n * 10 + s[o] - '0';
    }
    return n;
} 

int main(void) {
    WSADATA wsadata;
    char buffer[1024];
    char enviar[32];
    char respuesta[512];
    int bytesReceived;
    int i;
    int np;
    int ns;
    char primero[10];
    char segundo[10];
    float primero_double;
    float segundo_double;
    BOOL status = TRUE;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata) != 0) {
        printf("Error en WSAstartup\n");
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error al crear el socket\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return -2;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("212.129.38.224");
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(52002);

    if (connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress))== SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error al conectar\n");
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, (char *)&buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR || bytesReceived == 0) {
        printf("Error al recibir datos\n");
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';

    printf("Mensaje recibido: %s\nbytesReceived: %d\n", buffer, bytesReceived);

    i = 0;
    np = 0;
    ns = 0;
    while (buffer[i+160] != '\0') {    
        if (buffer[i+160] >= '0' && buffer[i+160] <= '9') {
            if (status) {
                primero[np] = buffer[i+160];
                ++np;
                if (buffer[i+160+1] == ' ') {
                    status = FALSE;
                }
            } else {
                segundo[ns] = buffer[i+160];
                ++ns;
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }
    primero[np] = '\0';
    segundo[ns] = '\0';
    printf("primero: %s, segundo: %s\n", primero, segundo);

    primero_double = toInt(primero);
    segundo_double = toInt(segundo);
    printf("primero_int: %.2f, segundo_int: %.2f\n", primero_double, segundo_double);

    primero_double = sqrt(primero_double);
    segundo_double = primero_double * segundo_double;

    segundo_double = round(segundo_double * 100) / 100;
    printf("redondeado: %.2f\n", segundo_double);
    sprintf(enviar,"%.2f\n", segundo_double);
    printf("enviar: %s", enviar);
    send(clientSocket, enviar, sizeof(enviar), 0);
    bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, (char *)&respuesta, sizeof(respuesta)-1, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR || bytesReceived == 0) {
        printf("Error al recibir datos\n");
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    respuesta[bytesReceived] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", respuesta);
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}


Claro, al tener un arreglo muy pequeño probablemente hayas estado escribiendo en el espacio de otra variable, y al escribir en esta modificas el contenido de la otra.
